# Why are none of my Windows Phone 7 unit tests running?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, windows-phone-7

I was TDDing away on my Windows Phone app using Jeff Wilcox's unit testing framework and somewhere along the way, every time I run my tests, it shows a blank screen with "Test assemblies" at the top and showing the total count of my tests as correct, but none of them are running.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
It turns out the problem is that I was defining a generic class in my assembly and the test framework was barfing on it.  Yikes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time I encountered this was when I had created some test classes that had generics involved. It seems the code that looked for the tests in the assembly bombs pretty badly then.

For example I had tests like

```
public class ProductViewModelTests : ViewModelTests<ProductViewModel> { ... }
```